# How to convert float into byte array?

Tags: javascript

I want to convert a float value like `26,4` into a byte array. Something like: `[51,51,-45,65]`. Another example: `32,2` > `[-51, -52, 0, 66]`.

I can do it in Arduino C++ and Python, but I don't see how to do it in JavaScript.

I have an input field in my HTML page where I want to write my float value and decode it before sending it to a Python script.

Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert "float" to bytes in Javascript without Float32Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935365/convert-float-to-bytes-in-javascript-without-float32array)

Comment: @ScottSauyet: Why without typed arrays? They make it so much simpler…

Comment: You're right.  This is not a duplicate of that one.  Yes, the typed arrays are clearly easier.  Retracted my close vote.

Comment: @Bergi Typed arrays are only for ES6. Older versions don't have them. But yes, the questions are related and complementary but not dupes

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Typed Arrays

First create a `Float32Array` which is a view on top of an actual byte-buffer (`ArrayBuffer`). We can allocate the buffer and view in a single operation:

```
var farr = new Float32Array(2);  // two indexes each 4 bytes
```

Store the floating point numbers. These will be stored in IEEE-754 format:

```
farr[0] = 26.4;
farr[1] = 32.2;
```

Now we can add another view for the underlying buffer, this time signed 8-bit view:

```
var barr = new Int8Array(farr.buffer);   // use the buffer of Float32Array view

console.log(barr);
// -> 51,51,-45,65,-51,-52,0,66
```

#### Live demo below

```js
var farr = new Float32Array(2);  // two indexes each 4 bytes
farr[0] = 26.4;
farr[1] = 32.2;

var barr = new Int8Array(farr.buffer);   // use the buffer of Float32Array view
console.log(barr);

document.querySelector("div").innerHTML =  barr[0]+","+barr[1]+","+barr[2]+","+barr[3]+","+barr[4]+","+barr[5]+","+barr[6]+","+barr[7];
```

```html
<div></div>
```