# Converting a Coordinate Value to a fixed64 protobuf object

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, protocol-buffers

I need to convert a Coordinate value, which is a float, to a protobuf object to send to a server
Problem is i need to convert it to a fixed64 object,
which is a 64bit long and javascript doesn't support numbers this long.

I am using [this](https://github.com/mafintosh/protocol-buffers) Library to create my protobuf Buffer.
I have found a working python snippet that tackles the same problem

```
def f2i(float):
  return struct.unpack('<Q', struct.pack('<d', float))[0]
```

This uses the struct library, and essentially converts the float into binary, and then back to a long.
I need to get the same output

So 51.366805 would become 4632426052430037296

Losing a little bit of precision is not the biggest issue, i just need to convert the value

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, JS doesn't support 64-bit integers, so you won't be able to get the *same* output. The closest you can get would be two 32-bit integers that represent the same 64-bit integer, which may or may not work depending on what kind of input your Protobuf library is expecting.

I'd suggest to have a look at the toFloat64() function in the accepted answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935365/convert-float-to-bytes-in-javascript-without-float32array).

Below is a slightly simplified version:

```
function toFloat64(value) {
  var hiWord = 0, loWord = 0;

  if (value <= -0.0) {
      hiWord = 0x80000000;
      value = -value;
  }

  var exponent = Math.floor(Math.log(value) / Math.log(2));
  var significand = Math.floor((value / Math.pow(2, exponent)) * Math.pow(2, 52));

  loWord = significand & 0xFFFFFFFF;
  significand /= Math.pow(2, 32);

  exponent += 1023;
  if (exponent >= 0x7FF) {
      exponent = 0x7FF;
      significand = 0;
  } else if (exponent < 0) exponent = 0;

  hiWord = hiWord | (exponent << 20);
  hiWord = hiWord | (significand & ~(-1 << 20));

  return [hiWord, loWord];
}
```

Let's give it a try:

```
var res = toFloat64(51.366805),
    hexHi = ('0000000' + res[0].toString(16)).substr(-8, 8),
    hexLo = ('0000000' + res[1].toString(16)).substr(-8, 8);

console.log('32-bit high word = 0x' + hexHi);
console.log('32-bit low word  = 0x' + hexLo);
console.log('64-bit result    = 0x' + hexHi + hexLo);
```

Output:

```
32-bit high word = 0x4049aef3
32-bit low word  = 0x775b8130
64-bit result    = 0x4049aef3775b8130
```

where 0x4049aef3775b8130 is indeed 4632426052430037296 once converted back to decimal.

If you really need an atomic JS number, your last option is to convert it back to an integer with 53-bit precision:

```
var int53 = parseInt(hexHi + hexLo, 16);
console.log(int53);
```

Output:

```
4632426052430037000
```