# Generate LLVM floating point hex literals in Javascript

Tags: javascript, floating-point, type-conversion, llvm

I'm trying to generate LLVM textual IR containing floating point literals. In order for this to work reliably, I need to be able to convert floats to their hexidecimal literal representation. For example, here is what the results should be:

```
f2hex(0.0001)    -> "0x3F1A36E2E0000000"
f2hex(0.1)       -> "0x3FB99999A0000000"
f2hex(1.1)       -> "0x3FF19999A0000000"
f2hex(3.33333)   -> "0x400AAAA8E0000000"
f2hex(4.9)       -> "0x40139999A0000000"
f2hex(111.99998) -> "0x405BFFFFA0000000"
```

I would settle for a detailed description of the algorithm (that does not rely on libraries or machine code which is unavailable from Javascript), but working Javascript code is even better.

The LLVM language reference describes the format here: http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#simple-constants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up leveraging the source for the [IEEE-754 Floating-Point Conversion Page](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/Decimal.html). I added the following two functions:

```
function llvm_double_hex(input) {
  ieee64 = new ieee(64)
  ieee64.Dec2Bin(input.toString())
  ieee64.BinString =
    ieee64.Convert2Bin(ieee64.DispStr, ieee64.StatCond64, ieee64.Result[0],
                         ieee64.BinaryPower, false)
  return '0x' + ieee64.Convert2Hex()
};
function llvm_float_hex(input) {
  var d64 = llvm_double_hex(input);
  return d64.replace(/(.*)........$/, "$1A0000000");
};
```

The second calls the first and zeros out the last half as expected for LLVM IR.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is to dump the binary representation of the double. Here's how it can be done in C:

```c
float f = ... // also works with double
char str[19];
sprintf(str, "0x%llX", f);
```

To do this in Javascript you need to extract the binary representation of the float. This isn't trivial, but fortunately it seems to already have a solution here on Stackoverflow: [Read/Write bytes of float in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4414077/242762) (and specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10564792/242762) seems convenient)