# Converting IEEE 754 from bit stream into float in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, floating-point, ieee-754

I have serialized 32-bit floating number using GO language function ([math.Float32bits](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Float32bits)) which returns the floating point number corresponding to the IEEE 754 binary representation.  This number is then serialized as 32-bit integer and is read into java script as byte array.

For example, here is actual number:

```
float: 2.8088086
as byte array:  40 33 c3 85
as hex: 0x4033c385
```

There is a [demo converter](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) that displays the same numbers.

I need to get that same floating number back from byte array in JavaScript and I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read/Write bytes of float in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414077/read-write-bytes-of-float-in-js)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Given the data you've described:

```
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(4);
var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
bytes[0] = 0x40;
bytes[1] = 0x33;
bytes[2] = 0xc3;
bytes[3] = 0x85;
```

We can retrieve the value as a floating-point number using a [`DataView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView):

```
var view = new DataView(buffer);
// If you only had a Uint8Array, you would use bytes.buffer instead of buffer.

console.log(view.getFloat32(0, false));
```

```
2.8088085651397705
```

```js
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(4);
var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
bytes[0] = 0x40;
bytes[1] = 0x33;
bytes[2] = 0xc3;
bytes[3] = 0x85;    

var view = new DataView(buffer);

console.log(view.getFloat32(0, false));
```

Comment: DataView is a great solution.  It is an internal application and I am using Chrome exclusively.  It works with it.

Answer (score 7):

a little bit different solution, if you cannot use DataView:

```js
var bytes = [ 0x40, 0x33, 0xc3, 0x85 ];
var bits = (bytes[0] << 24) | (bytes[1] << 16) | (bytes[2] << 8) | (bytes[3]);
var sign = ((bits >>> 31) == 0) ? 1.0 : -1.0;
var e = ((bits >>> 23) & 0xff);
var m = (e == 0) ? (bits & 0x7fffff) << 1 : (bits & 0x7fffff) | 0x800000;
var f = sign * m * Math.pow(2, e - 150);

document.write(f);
```

Comment: Just for future readers wondering why most implementations use `127` in `m * Math.pow(2, e - 127)`: above, `m * Math.pow(2, e - 150)` equals `m * Math.pow(2, -23) * Math.pow(2, e - 127)` and is a nice optimisation to add the 24th [implicit leading bit in the mantissa](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html).

Answer (score 0):

My answer is like @Jeremys answer, except for small changes. Please use now `const`/`let` and `Float32Array`/`Float64Array` instead of `DataView`. I solved it like this:

```
// 0x40a00000 is "5" in float/IEEE-754 32bit.
// You can check this here: https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html
// MSB (Most significant byte) is at highest index
const bytes = [0x00, 0x00, 0xa0, 0x40];
// The buffer is like a raw view into memory.
const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(bytes.length);
// The Uint8Array uses the buffer as its memory.
// This way we can store data byte by byte
const byteArray = new Uint8Array(buffer);
for (let i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
  byteArray[i] = bytes[i];
}

// float array uses the same buffer as memory location
const floatArray = new Float32Array(buffer);

// floatValue is a "number", because a number in javascript is a
// double (IEEE-754 @ 64bit) => it can hold f32 values
const floatValue = floatArray[0];

// prints out "5"
console.log(`${JSON.stringify(bytes)} as f32 is ${floatValue}`);

// double / f64
// const doubleArray = new Float64Array(buffer);
// const doubleValue = doubleArray[0];
```