# Converting a string of packed bytes into an array of floats in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, encoding

### Context

I know that in python you can create an a string representing the packed bytes of an array doing something like such:

```
import numpy as np

np.array([1, 2], dtype=np.int32).tobytes() 
# returns '\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00'

np.array([1, 2], dtype=np.float32).tobytes() 
# returns '\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00\x00@'
```

And they can be decoded using [np.fromstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html)

### Question

Currently, my Javascript is receiving a string of packed bytes that encodes an array of floats (i.e. `'\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00\x00@'`) and I need to decode the array -- what is the best way to do this?

(if it were an array of ints I imagine I could use [text-encoding](https://github.com/inexorabletash/text-encoding) to pull the bytes and then just multiply and add appropriately...)

Thanks,

Comment: So I suppose we could manually do the conversion -- apparently that's how [protobufs](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/js/binary/utils.js#L358) do it... (or maybe we could hijack their method...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you have to convert a string into a buffer, and then create a `Float32Array` on that buffer. Optionally, spread it to create a normal `Array`:

```js
str = '\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00\x00@'

bytes = Uint8Array.from(str, c => c.charCodeAt(0))
floats = new Float32Array(bytes.buffer)

console.log(floats)

console.log([...floats]);
```

Comment: Haha, seems we had just resolved it in the comment above! But appreciate you confirming :)

Answer (score 2):

Floating-point representation can vary from platform to platform. It isn't a good idea to use a binary serialized form of a floating-point number to convey a number from one machine to another.

That said, the answers to this question *might* help you, provided the encoding used by the JavaScript matches that of the source of the numbers:

[Read/Write bytes of float in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414077/read-write-bytes-of-float-in-js)

Comment: Interesting, that post gave me a good idea... we could read the string into a uint8 buffer and then use a [Float32Array view](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Float32Array) on the buffer....