# Send numpy array as bytes from python to JS through Flask

Tags: javascript, python, numpy, flask, data-conversion

A numpy array should be sent from python to JS through flask. I don't want to jsonify it and send as it would increase the size of the response and eventually the response time. So I thought I could convert numpy into bytes using tobytes(), send the bytes to JS through flask and convert the bytes back to float in JS and found [Converting a string of packed bytes into an array of floats in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41903504/converting-a-string-of-packed-bytes-into-an-array-of-floats-in-javascript) answer helpful.

The list of operations are

```
byte_arr = np.array([5.6], dtype=np.float32).tobytes()  # Used one value just to make it simple
return byte_arr  # Bytes can be directly sent from flask as response
```

In JS,

```
str = response.text
bytes = Uint8Array.from(str, c => c.charCodeAt(0))
floats = new Float32Array(bytes.buffer)
```

But when converting to float in JS, I am not getting the correct values. When debugging I found that in JS some values in Uint8 array are not matching with the byte values that are sent from python.

```
JS: console.log(bytes)  // [51, 51, 255, 64]
Python: for val in byte_arr: print(val, end=" ")  // 51, 51, 179, 64
```

Just to verify, I created another client in python, made the same request and converted the response bytes to float. I encountered the same issue here also. So I narrowed down that the problem is on the server side not on the client side. One more interesting thing I found when playing with multiple values are, only the numbers which are greater than 127 (I guess so) are getting converted to 255.

While trying some random hacks, I tried to convert the byte integer to character using chr() method of python before sending the response and the conversion on the client side worked.

```
byte_arr = np.array([5.6], dtype=np.float32).tobytes()
byte_arr_char = "".join([chr(i) for i in byte_arr])
return byte_arr_char
```

But the question I have is, Is this an ideal solution or am I doing some hack here to make it work? Can anyone help me to understand why sending plain bytes without chr() doesn't work?

Comment: Can you edit into the question what the value of `byte_arr` is in python, and what the value of `response.text` is in JS?

Comment: How is the `response` received? Are you making sure to [set a suitable response type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data)?

Comment: @CharlieWindolf Sure. But the value in JS script is all question marks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't set the [MIME type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types) explicitly, I think Flask will treat it as text data. Your browser seems to have decoded the binary data with ASCII, which can explain why only values larger than 127 were affected.

Therefore, please try setting the `Content-Type` of the response in Flask:

```py
@app.route('/your/url/to/numpy/data')
def get_nparray():
    your_np_array = np.array([5.6], dtype=np.float32)
    response = flask.make_response(your_np_array.tobytes())
    response.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
    # response.headers.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='np-array.bin')
    return response
```

Alternatively, there is a helper function `flask.send_file` to construct the response in a single line. Please find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25150805/6238076).

Besides this error, also pay attention to the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your binary data, which is hardware specific. I would refer you to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7876265/6238076) (*Javascript Typed Arrays and Endianness*).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works the way I wanted. Also, I read about the usage of send_file but the data will be received as an image, in that case, I wasn't sure how to receive the image as an array/text.

Comment: I actually encountered another issue here. I am able to get the correct response in python but in JS where I am using angular's $http to make the response, I am still stuck with the same issue. The response I get is not a "application/octet-stream" response. This summarizes the problem https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10349. Any solution for this?