# javascript polynomial calculation accuracy

Tags: javascript, precision

I'm working on a typescript/javascript numeric project, I obvserved some cases of accuracy issue, as compared to c++ calculation result. I searched in google and v8-dev group, bascially everyone is saying javascript number has the same accuracy as c++ double type.

I'm thinking maybe some of the accuracy issue is due to algorithm, below is an example of polynomial calculation:

`typescript` code, nothing fancy, just basic complex number operations( add / sub / multiplication / division )

```
class Complex {
  constructor(r: number = 0.0, i: number = 0.0) {
    this._real = r;
    this._imag = i;
  }

  _real: number;
  _imag: number;
}

namespace Complex {
  export function add(c1: Complex, c2: Complex): Complex {
    return new Complex(c1._real + c2._real, c1._imag + c2._imag);
  }

  export function sub(c1: Complex, c2: Complex): Complex {
    return new Complex(c1._real - c2._real, c1._imag - c2._imag);
  }

  export function mul(c1: Complex, c2: Complex): Complex {
    return new Complex(
        c1._real * c2._real - c1._imag * c2._imag,
        c1._real * c2._imag + c1._imag * c2._real);
  }

  export function div(c1: Complex, c2: Complex): Complex {
    return new Complex(
        (c1._real * c2._real + c1._imag * c2._imag) /
            (c2._real * c2._real + c2._imag * c2._imag),
        (c1._imag * c2._real - c1._real * c2._imag) /
            (c2._real * c2._real + c2._imag * c2._imag));
  }
}

const g: Complex = new Complex(4.0, -6.000000000000001e-006);
const D: Complex = new Complex(4.0000000000086198, -6.39999999998621e-006);
const G: Complex = Complex.div(Complex.sub(g, D), Complex.add(g, D));
```

js result for G:
`Complex {_real: -1.1548604230893913e-12, _imag: 4.9999999996432116e-8}`

c++ code doing the same calculation, build with mingw-64:

```
#include<limits>
#include<iostream>
#include<complex>

typedef std::numeric_limits< double > dbl;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout.precision(dbl::max_digits10);

    std::complex<double> g = std::complex<double>(4.0, -6.000000000000001e-006);
    std::complex<double> D = std::complex<double>(4.0000000000086198, -6.39999999998621e-006);
    const std::complex<double> G = (g-D)/(g+D);

    std::cout << G;

    return 0;
}
```

c++ result for G: `(-1.1549714453918537e-012,4.9999999996432057e-008)`

I know the difference is not big, but I have other statistic calculatoin which is more complicated than this and didn't lose accuracy, and this part is in the middle of the calculation, if there's accuracy dip here, the final result will be even less accurate.

Does this mean c++ code is optimized? 
How to improve js code to have the same accuracy here?
thank you!

Comment: i am also having same issue

Comment: It's probably because the built-in `std::complex` class has different implementation of the arithmetic operators than your JS class. What happens if you implement your own `complex` class using the same algorithm?

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for the respnse, I tried using same code as https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/3b0a1c9cfa607840519e49e8589815c25078c3df/stl/inc/complex#547, result is the same

Comment: Any idea how many bits are different? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414077/read-write-bytes-of-float-in-js for how to get the raw binary of a JS float.