# Bitwise operator for modulo and rounding

Tags: javascript, numbers, logic, bitwise-operators

I have a function which takes a fractional number, and converts it to an integer combined with a binary exponent.

For example, `get_whole_number(10.5)` will return `=> 21, 1`, where

- `21` is the integer
- `1` is the power of `2` you must divide the `21` by to get the original float number (`21/(2**1) = 10.5`).

So far I have this function, and **it works** but it is **inefficient and slow**:

```js
function get_whole_number(number, exponent=0) {
    if(number%1 == 0) return [number, exponent];
    exponent++;
    number *= 2;
    if(exponent >= 500) return [Math.round(number), exponent];
    return get_whole_number(number, exponent);
};

console.log(
  get_whole_number(1.125).join("/2^"));
```

To make it faster, I wanted to replace some operations, notably `number%1` and `Math.round` with bitwise operations.

### So my question is, how do I go about replacing `% 1` and `round()` with bitwise operators?

I was thinking that I could use:

- `if((number & number) == number)` instead of `if(number%1 == 0)` because bitwise operations ignore the fractional part of a number; but this only works sometimes.
- `(number | number)` instead of `Math.round(number)` but this just truncates the value.

Comment: _"...but it is inefficient and slow"_ - Is it? Who told you that?

Comment: @Andreas maybe it isn't exactly slow, but it could be faster, and is wasting some computation time which could be avoided

Comment: 99.99999% of times these optimizations are not necessary or do not have such a significant effect. Not only are you wasting your time focusing on that, you are also making the code less readable, more prone to undefined behavior, not resolving the real performance issues, and more importantly not focusing on features and usability.

Comment: [What optimizations are premature?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/79938/what-optimizations-are-premature)

Comment: The problem might just be me, but `get_whole_number` just makes no sense to me. What does it do? Why? What does it return? I'm more confused the more i look at it.

Comment: @Jesper it creates two integers from one float. So I use it when representing a fraction in terms of binary using floating-point notation when I have the desired sizes of the mantissa and exponent.

Comment: If you're talking about efficiency, like I said before a better approach would be probably to find a better algorithm rather than optimizing the operations of the same one. In your case you can use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414077/read-write-bytes-of-float-in-js

Comment: @AlphaHowl I recommend asking this in [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) they have given me good pointers in the past.

Comment: @asyncawait thank you that is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace Math.round by double negation bitwise ~~

```
function get_whole_number(number, exponent=0) {
if(number%1 == 0) return [number, exponent];
exponent++;
number *= 2;
if(exponent >= 500) return [~~(number), exponent];
return get_whole_number(number, exponent);};
```