# How to convert a float to binary using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the Example:

For example, suppose we have a float `13.4`. In binary, it can be written as: `1101.01100110011001100110011001100110011兮`.

Suppose the system stores bits up to `10` **decimal places**. So `13.4` is stored as: `1101.0110011001` (only `10` decimal places now)

Because of this change, if you convert `1101.0110011001` back to base `10`, you get `13.399414`. In essence `13.399414` is stored rather than `13.4` in this case!

So given a floating point in base `10`, an integer `n` which represents the number of decimal places as defined above, output the stored value of the float to three decimal places.

So How can i convert using javascript:- input `13.4` and output `13.399`

Comment: Number's in javascript have a toString method that should help - oh wait, you still want 13.4 to output as 13.399 - why?

Comment: any solutions??using javascript

Comment: 13.4 is 13.4 ... it isn't 13.399 ... what about 13.5, should that be 13.499? I guess I don't understand the question :p

Comment: Read the above Example: carefully

Comment: Math.Round() didnt work?

Comment: @JaromandaX I think the question is how to translate the story into actual Javascript code in order to get the same result.

Comment: yes..exactly..how to convert using javascipt..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a floating point number to its binary representation (IEEE 754) in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096646/how-to-convert-a-floating-point-number-to-its-binary-representation-ieee-754-i)

Comment: Which in turn really makes me wonder why ppl are upvoting this question. It shows no research efford. There is no code. Essentialy the questions is: _Please do my work for me_

Comment: `(parseInt((13.4 * 1024).toString(2),2)/1024).toFixed(3)` - the 1024 is 10 binary digits after the `.`

Comment: i have tried that one already..any solutions...comment here

Comment: but that one works, @amitkumar

Comment: `Number((parseInt((13.4 * 1024).toString(2),2)/1024).toFixed(3))`

Comment: `In essence 13.399414 is stored rather than 13.4 in this case!` actually, I'd say, in essence, 13.399414 and 13.4 are equal in this arbitrary 10 binary digit system you've developed for no apparent reason

Comment: Ok, I m trying..

Comment: for base 5 what should i do?

Comment: @amitkumar If you're going to keep tacking on requests, can you at least explain _why_ you want to do this?

Comment: `1101.0110011001` does not have 10 decimal digits in its fractional part, it does have 10 *binary* digits?!

Comment: "*So given a floating point in base 10*" - you mean represented as a string?

Answer (score 0):

Going off of the comment by @Jaromanda X

```
function cut(num, base, len) {
    base = Math.pow(2, base);
    return (parseInt((num * base).toString(2), 2) / base).toFixed(len);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a number with a desired number of fractional digits by shifting it to the left by that number of places, dropping the remaining digits on the right by flooring it, and shifting it back right. This works in any base - base 2 in your case:

```
Math.floor(13.4 * 2**10) / 2**10
Math.floor(13.4 * Math.pow(2, 10)) / Math.pow(2, 10)
Math.floor(13.4 * (1<<10)) / (1<<10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Basenumber.js](https://github.com/AlexSp3/Basenumber.js) library. Just create an instance in **decimal**, an parse it to **binary**:

```js
// Set precision decimals you want
Base.setDecimals(100);

// create instance in decimal
let x = Base(13.4);

// Transform x to binary
let y = x.toBin();

console.log(x.valueOf());
console.log(y.valueOf());

// Transform y to decimal again
let z = y.toDec();

// Since 13.4 has no exact binary representation it would not be accurate
console.log(z.valueOf());

// But you can round the value so get again 13.4
let rounded = z.round(10);   // round 10 decimals

console.log(rounded.valueOf());
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/AlexSp3/Basenumber.js@main/BaseNumber.min.js'></script>
```